# What bodies (Koshas or layers) do Devas, Trimurthis and their Shaktis (consorts) have?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, gods, brahma, shakti

The two questions [What are Five Layers (Pancha Kosha) of Human?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3073/3500) and [Where does a Soul attached to the Body?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6758/3500) explain various ***koshas*** (Sheaths) of human body. Trimurthi and their respective Shaktis are believed to be different aspects of **Supreme Brahman.** Same is the case of Devas but they are less powerful than trimurtis and their Shaktis.

- **What *Koshas* do Trimurthis and their Shaktis have?** For example, Goddess Saraswati represents Knowledge. Does she have *Vijananmaya kosha* and *Anandamaya Kosha*?
- **What about *Devas* living in Swarga Loka?**. Agni Deva represents fire but has form. What Koshas do devas have?

Comment: There is a description of Lord Vishnu as seen by Garuda in the Garuda Purana where he describes Vishnu being enveloped in his own creation i.e. aham, mahat, all 10 indriyas 5 tanmatras and 5 mahabhutas, etc.

Comment: @The Destroyer check inbox email

Comment: @archit can you tell reference

Comment: @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud the reference is Garuda Purana, Dharmakanda - Pretakalpa first chapter should be after verse 20-30 or so

Comment: All the devatas in material existence, ie material world, have material bodies, except for Lord Vishnu who is said to be paramatma, and thus bodyless, unembodied, disembodied self, or that is to say Lord Vishnu doesn't have material body.

Answer (score 1):

Devatas are psychological realities (metaphysical entities). They are not physical beings. They don't have Koshas. They are aspects that manifest in our Consciousness. They are experienced within us as our vital energy rises. [a typical description of God](https://www.thekundaliniyoga.org/hindu_gods/what_is_god.aspx). They manifest in the state of Turiya (which is actually the substratum of all the three states that humans pass through - waking, sleeping and deep dreamless sleep state).

They are metaphors as in the legend of the tussle between Brahma and Vishnu and their sighting the pillar of fire (Shiva). Ramana Maharishi states that...

> Vishnu represents the **intellect** and Brahma the **ego**, while Siva is **Atma**, the spirit.

Ramana Maharishi precisely captured the nature of this confusion in one such rare discussions with one of his disciples ([page 375](https://selfdefinition.org/ramana/Talks-with-Sri-Ramana-Maharshi--complete.pdf)):

> Later Sri Bhagavan continued: The intricate maze of philosophy of
> different schools is said to clarify matters and reveal the Truth. But
> in fact they create confusion where no confusion need exist. To
> understand anything there must be the Self. The Self is obvious. Why
> not remain as the Self? What need to explain the non-self? Take the
> Vedanta for instance: They say there are fifteen kinds of prana. The
> student is made to commit the names to memory and also their
> functions. The air goes up and is called prana; goes down and is
> called apana; operates the indriyas and is called something. Why all
> this? Why do you classify, give names and enumerate the functions, and
> so on? Is it not enough to know that one prana does the whole work?
> The antahkarana thinks, desires, wills, reasons, etc., and each
> function is attributed to one name such as mind, intellect, etc. Has
> anyone seen the pranas or the antahkaranas? Have they any real
> existence? They are mere conceptions. When and where will such conceptions end?
>
> Consider the following: A
> man sleeps. He says on waking that he slept. The question is asked:
> ‘Why does he not say in his sleep that he is sleeping?’ The answer is
> given that he is sunk in the Self and cannot speak, like a man who has
> dived in water to bring out something from the bottom. The diver
> cannot speak under water; when he has actually recovered the articles
> he comes out and speaks. Well, what is the explanation?
>
> Being in water, water will flow into his mouth if he were to open the mouth for
> speaking. Is it not simple? But the philosopher is not content with
> this simple fact. He explains, saying that **fire** is the **deity** presiding
> over speech; that it is inimical to water and therefore cannot
> function! This is called philosophy and the learners are struggling to
> learn all this! Is it not a sheer waste of time? Again the Gods are
> said to preside over the limbs and senses of the individual (vyashti).
> They are the limbs and senses of Virat (samashti). So they go on
> explaining **Hiranyagarbha**, etc. Why should confusion be created and
> then explained away? Ah! Fortunate is the man who does not involve
> himself in this maze!

Comment: Are the devas aspects manifest in the Divine consciousness or the individual human consciousnesses? Could they exist and have power, work wonders, even if humanity never existed?

Comment: Your use of the contradictory words "metaphysical", and "psychological" are confusing me. Metaphysical entities are on a HIGHER, sublimer, and more exalted order of reality than our reality, while psychological beings are on a LOWER order of reality than our reality. We need the metaphysical order to exist for our order to exist, but the metaphysical order of reality is perfectly capable of existing without this reality.

Comment: What beings occupy a metaphysically higher order of reality than humans do? Which beings are metaphysically between humans and Bhagavan?