# Do Hindu gods have an atman?

Tags: vishnu, gods, atma

I have looked both online and in a library for a source that contained information about this question, but could not find it.

Could somebody tell me if Gods have an atman?

Comment: Related [What bodies (Koshas or layers) do Devas, Trimurthis and their Shaktis (consorts) have?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10118/3500)

Answer (score 5):

> Brahman was this
>   before; therefore it
>   knew even the Ātma
>   (soul, himself). I am
>   Brahman, therefore it
>   became all. And
>   whoever among the
>   gods had this
>   enlightenment, also
>   became That. It is the
>   same with the sages,
>   the same with men.
>   Whoever knows the
>   self as “I am
>   Brahman,” becomes
>   all this universe. **Even
>   the gods cannot
>   prevail against him,
>   for he becomes their
>   Ātma.** Now, if a man
>   worships another god,
>   thinking: “He is one
>   and I am another,” he
>   does not know. He is
>   like an animal to the
>   gods. As many
>   animals serve a man,
>   so does each man
>   serve the gods. Even
>   if one animal is taken
>   away, it causes
>   anguish; how much
>   more so when many
>   are taken away?
>   Therefore it is not
>   pleasing to the gods
>   that men should know
>   this.
>
> **— [Brihadaranyaka
>   Upanishad 1.4.10](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/upanishads/brihad.asp)**

They have atman.

As we know **Indra** spent 101 years with Prajapati uderstanding the self whereas the demon king from the first time getting an answer as the body is the self got away but indra came again and again to Prajapati after getting an answer and spend 101 years with Prajapati learning self and that's why gods are all prevalent.

CHANDOGYA UPNISHAD BOOK:VIII

> **SEVENTH KHANDA**
>
> 1. Prajapati said: 'The Self
>      which is free from sin, free
>      from old age, from death
>      and grief, from hunger and
>      thirst, which desires
>      nothing but what it ought
>      to desire, and imagines
>      nothing but what it ought
>      to imagine, that it is which
>      we must search out, that it
>      is which we must try to
>      understand. He who has
>      searched out that Self and
>      understands it, obtains all
>      worlds and all desires.'
> 2. The Devas (gods) and
>      Asuras (demons) both heard
>      these words, and said :
>      'Well, let us search for that
>      Self by which, if one has
>      searched it out, all worlds
>      and all desires are
>      obtained.'
>      Thus saying Indra went
>      from the Devas, Virokana
>      from the Asuras, and both,
>      without having
>      communicated with each
>      other, approached
>      Prajapati, holding fuel in
>      their hands, as is the
>      custom for pupils
>      approaching their master.
> 3. They dwelt there as
>      pupils for thirty-two years.
>      Then Prajapati asked them:
>      'For what purpose have you
>      both dwelt here?'
>      They replied: 'A saying of
>      yours is being repeated, viz.
>      "the Self which is free from
>      sin, free from old age, from
>      death and grief, from
>      hunger and thirst, which
>      desires nothing but what it
>      ought to desire, and
>      imagines nothing but what
>      it ought to imagine, that it
>      is which we must search
>      out, that it is which we
>      must try to understand. He
>      who has searched out that
>      Self and understands it,
>      obtains all worlds and all
>      desires." Now we both have
>      dwelt here because we wish
>      for that Self.'
>      Prajapati said to them: 'The
>      person that is seen in the
>      eye, that is the Self. This is
>      what I have said. This is
>      the immortal, the fearless,
>      this is Brahman.'
>      They asked: 'Sir, he who is
>      perceived in the water, and
>      he who is perceived in a
>      mirror, who is he?'
>      He replied: 'He himself
>      indeed is seen in all these
>      .'
>
> **EIGHTH KHANDA.**
>
> 1. 'Look at your Self in 
>      pan of water, and whatever
>      you do not understand of
>      your Self, come and tell
>      me.'
>      They looked in the water-
>      pan. Then Prajapati said to
>      them: 'What do you see?'
>      They said: 'We both see the
>      self thus altogether, a
>      picture even to the very
>      hairs and nails.'
> 2. Prajapati said to them:
>      'After you have adorned
>      yourselves, have put on
>      your best clothes and
>      cleaned yourselves, look
>      again into the water-pan.
>      They, after having adorned
>      themselves, having put on
>      their best clothes and
>      cleaned themselves, looked
>      into the water-pan.
>      Prajapati said: 'What do
>      you see?'
> 3. They said: 'Just as we
>      are, well adorned, with our
>      best clothes and clean, thus
>      we are both there, Sir, well
>      adorned, with our best
>      clothes and clean.'
>      Prajapati said: 'That is the
>      Self, this is the immortal,
>      the fearless, this is
>      Brahman.'
>      Then both went away
>      satisfied in their hearts.
> 4. And Prajapati, looking
>      after them, said: 'They both
>      go away without having
>      perceived and without
>      having known the Self, and
>      whoever of these two,
>      whether Devas or Asuras,
>      will follow this doctrine
>      (upanishad), will perish.'
>      Now Virokana, satisfied in
>      his heart, went to the
>      Asuras and preached that
>      doctrine to them, that the
>      self (the body) alone is to
>      be worshipped, that the self
>      (the body) alone is to be
>      served, and that he who
>      worships the self and serves
>      the self, gains both worlds,
>      this and the next.
> 5. Therefore they call even
>      now a man who does not
>      give alms here, who has no
>      faith, and offers no
>      sacrifices, an Asura, for this
>      is the doctrine (upanishad)
>      of the Asuras. They deck
>      out the body of the dead
>      with perfumes, flowers, and
>      fine raiment by way of
>      ornament, and think they
>      will thus conquer that
>      world.
>
> **NINTH KHANDA**
>
> 1. But Indra, before he had
>      returned to the Devas, saw
>      this difficulty. As this self
>      (the shadow in the water) is
>      well adorned, when the
>      body is well adorned, well
>      dressed, when the body is
>      well dressed, well cleaned,
>      if the body is well cleaned,
>      that self will also be blind,
>      if the body is blind, lame, if
>      the body is lame, crippled,
>      if the body is crippled, and
>      will perish in fact as soon
>      as the body perishes.
>      Therefore I see no good in
>      this (doctrine).
> 2. Taking fuel in his hand
>      he came again as a pupil to
>      Prajapati. Prajapati said to
>      him: 'Maghavat (Indra), as
>      you went away with
>      Virokana, satisfied in your
>      heart, for what purpose did
>      you come back?'
>      He said : 'Sir, as this self
>      (the shadow) is well
>      adorned, when the body is
>      well adorned, well dressed,
>      when the body is well
>      dressed, well cleaned, if the
>      body is well cleaned, that
>      self will also be blind, if
>      the body is blind, lame, if
>      the body is lame, crippled,
>      if the body is crippled, and
>      will perish in fact as soon
>      as the body perishes.
>      Therefore I see no good in
>      this (doctrine).'
> 3. 'So it is indeed,
>      Maghavat,' replied
>      Prajapati; 'but I shall
>      explain him (the true Self)
>      further to
>      you. Live with me another
>      thirty-two years.'
>      He lived with him another
>      thirty-two years, and then
>      Pragapati said:
>
> **TENTH KHANDA**
>
> 1. 'He who moves about
>      happy in dreams, he is the
>      Self, this is the immortal,
>      the fearless, this is
>      Brahman.'
>      Then Indra went away
>      satisfied in his heart. But
>      before he had returned to
>      the Devas, he saw this
>      difficulty. Although it is
>      true that that self is not
>      blind, even if the body is
>      blind, nor lame, if the body
>      is lame, though it is true
>      that that self is not
>      rendered faulty by the
>      faults of it (the body),
> 2. Nor struck when it (the
>      body) is struck, nor lamed
>      when it is lamed, yet it is
>      as if they struck him (the
>      self) in dreams, as if they
>      chased him'. He becomes
>      even conscious, as it were,
>      of pain, and sheds tears.
>      Therefore I see no good in
>      this.
> 3. Taking fuel in his hands,
>      he went again as a pupil to
>      Prajapati. Prajapati said
>      to him: 'Maghavat, as you
>      went away satisfied in your
>      heart, for what purpose did
>      you come back?'
>      He said: 'Sir, although it is
>      true that that self is not
>      blind even if the body is
>      blind, nor lame, if the body
>      is lame, though it is true
>      that that self is not
>      rendered faulty by the
>      faults of it (the body),
> 4. Nor struck when it (the
>      body) is struck, nor lamed
>      when it is lamed, yet it is
>      as if they struck him (the
>      self) in dreams, as if they
>      chased him. He becomes
>      even conscious, as it were,
>      of pain, and sheds tears.
>      Therefore I see no good in
>      this.'
>      'So it is indeed, Maghavat,'
>      replied Prajapati; 'but I
>      shall explain him (the true
>      Self) further to you. Live
>      with me another thirty-two
>      years.' He lived with him
>      another thirty-two years.
>      Then Prajapati said:
>
> **ELEVENTH KHANDA**
>
> 1. 'When a man being
>      asleep, reposing, and at
>      perfect rest', sees no
>      dreams, that is the Self, this
>      is the immortal, the
>      fearless, this is Brahman.'
>      Then Indra went away
>      satisfied.in his heart. But
>      before he had returned to
>      the Devas, he saw this
>      difficulty. In truth he thus
>      does not know himself (his
>      self) that he is I, nor does
>      he know anything that
>      exists. He is gone to utter
>      annihilation. I see no good
>      in this.
> 2. Taking fuel in his hand
>      he went again as a pupil to
>      Prajapati. Prajapati said to
>      him: 'Maghavat, as you went
>      away satisfied in your heart,
>      for what purpose did you
>      come back?'
>      He said: 'Sir, in that way he
>      does not know himself (his
>      self ) that he is I, nor does
>      he know anything that
>      exists. He is gone to utter
>      annihilation. I see no good
>      in this.'
> 3. 'So it is indeed,
>      Maghavat,' replied Prajapati
>      'but I shall explain him (the
>      true Self) further to
>      you, and nothing more than
>      this . Live here otherfive
>      years.
>      **'He lived there other five
>      years. This made in all one
>      hundred and one years, and
>      therefore it is said that
>      Indra Maghavat lived one
>      hundred and one years as a
>      pupil with Prajapati.**
>      Prajapati said to him:
>
> **TWELFTH KHANDA**
>
> 1. 'Maghavat, this body is
>      mortal and always held by
>      death. It is the abode of
>      that Self which is immortal
>      and without body. When in
>      the body (by thinking this
>      body is I and I am this
>      body) the Self is held by
>      pleasure and pain. So long
>      as he is in the body, he
>      cannot get free from
>      pleasure and pain. But
>      when he is free of the body
>      (when he knows himself
>      different from the body),
>      then neither pleasure nor
>      pain touches him'.
> 2. 'The wind is without
>      body, the cloud, lightning,
>      and thunder are without
>      body (without hands, feet,
>      &c.) Now as these, arising
>      from this heavenly ether
>      (space), appear in their own
>      form, as soon as they have
>      approached the highest
>      light,
> 3. 'Thus does that serene
>      being, arising from this
>      body, appear in its own
>      form, as soon as it has
>      approached the highest
>      light (the knowledge of
>      Self) . He (in that state) is
>      the highest person (uttama
>      purusha). He moves about
>      there laughing (or eating),
>      playing, and rejoicing (in
>      his mind), be it with
>      women, carriages, or
>      relatives, never minding
>      that body into which he was
>      born.
>      'Like as a horse attached to
>      a cart, so is the spirit
>      (prana, pragnatman)
>      attached to this body.
> 4. 'Now where the sight has
>      entered into the void (the
>      open space, the black pupil
>      of the eye), there is the
>      person of the eye, the eye
>      itself is the instrument of
>      seeing. He who knows, let
>      me smell this, he is the
>      Self, the nose is the
>      instrument of smelling. He
>      who knows, let me say this,
>      he is the Self, the tongue is
>      the instrument of saying.
>      He who knows, let me hear
>      this, he is the Self, the ear
>      is the instrument of
>      hearing.
> 5. 'He who knows, let me
>      think this, he is the Self,
>      the mind is his divine eye .
>      He, the Self, seeing these
>      pleasures (which to others
>      are hidden like a buried
>      treasure of gold) through
>      his divine eye, i. e. the
>      mind, rejoices.
>      **'The Devas who are in the
>      world of Brahman meditate
>      on that Self (as taught by
>      Prajapati to Indra, and by
>      Indra to the Devas).
>      Therefore all worlds belong
>      to them, and all desires. He
>      who knows that Self and
>      understands it, obtains all
>      worlds and all desires.'**
>      Thus said Prajapati, yea,
>      thus said Prajapati.

link:—http://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/upanishads/chandogya.asp