# What are the differences between goddess and female human beings?

Tags: women, goddess, lakshmi, durga, parvati

Other than goddess being God and women being human are there any other considerable differences between goddess and women? If yes, can you list them. Also could you please explain why such differences exist?

By saying differences, I mean-

- Biological differences
  (Do goddess menstruate?, any other biological differences)
- Differences in way of thinking (mindset, intelligence etc)
- General Behavioral differences (feminine behavior)
- Any other differences

Comment: Related [What bodies (Koshas or layers) do Devas, Trimurthis and their Shaktis (consorts) have?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10118/3500)

Comment: The actual difference is between deity and human. Nothing to bother on gender I think.

Answer (score 2):

The word देवी comes from the root दिव् which means they are made of light.Alternatively, they are the ones who advise pravitti and nivritti to all.

> देवी¦ स्त्री देवयति प्रवृत्तिनिवृत्त्युपदेशेन यथाधिकारं व्यव-हारयति सर्वान् देव--णिच् अच् ङीप्, दीव्यति दिव-अच् पचादौ देवट् इति निर्देशात् टित्त्वात् ङीप्[Page3750-a+ 38] देवस्य पत्नी ङीष वा। Ref :https://sa.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%80

They take forms only when required. Natures are mentioned in the dhyanamantras. For example Devi Vishalakshi is known to be very angry.The age is also mentioned in some dhyanamantras.

The dhyanamantras of many devis are available in Vrihattantrasaara,Niruttara-Tantra, Kalika-Puraana etc.For examle, Vishalakshi is mentioned to be always sixteen years old. Devis are not bound by time and so they do not age.Dhumavati is depicted old. Otherwise normally all devis are purnayauvana. Their complexions are also mentioned in the dhyanamantras.

Reference : Bharatiya Shaktisadhanaa o shaaktasahiya, Upendrakumar Das, Vol.1, RMIC, page 534-537).

Comment: What are Dhyanamantras?

Comment: Dhyanamantra is the mantra that describes the details of the deity. Its found either in tantra or in puran where the details of the deity is given. Tantrasar and Kalilapuran are sources of many such mantras.

Comment: Regarding etymology of word Devi, I think [sanskrit wiktionary](https://sa.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%80) may be useful source to cite :)

Comment: Good, but the dhyanamantras not given.

Comment: As I said I don't know about Dhyanamantras and as you said it can be from Tantra or Purana, you should find and cite them. You may visit [Agama and Tantra](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53977/agama-and-tantra) room for discussing mantra from Tantra.