# What is Vayu Siddhi and how to attain it? Are siddhis necessary for Moksha achievement?

Tags: yoga, moksha, meditation, siddhi

Reading the Samhita of Shiva and some other recommendations of the Swami Sivananda Saraswaati, I came across the term **vayu siddhi**.
The English translation roughly explains what it is but I wish to better understand what it is, if **is it necessary to attain this siddhi in order to get Moksha?** and more generically **in which way are the  siddhis relevant  in the reaching of the Moksha?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below linked and copied pasted set of Q&A about one answers about Devas Koshas may partially give a hint to answer my still unanswered question.

[What bodies (Koshas or layers) do Devas, Trimurthis and their Shaktis (consorts) have?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10118/22667)

I give you the formula of the synthesis before you read one part of the thesis contained into that answer, that is:
Vayu Siddhi is that capacity of the physical body to leave the ground, while in deep sadhana- samadhi. Therefore the human body can win gravity.
Then why it is important to acquire such a capacity [according to Yog Shiva Samhita in particular]?

---

Note: Sri Swami Sivananda Saraswati does not state that this is important, and discourage the practitioners to get enchanted with the 8 major Siddhis which are told to be "happenings", whilst the edition of Yog Shiva Samhita in my hands state that this Siddhi is important.

---

While the samadhi process is mature enough, just before the Moksha arrives, the body must have learned to win the gravity as this is a correspondence to the jiva that have overcome tatmatras and indryias.

Only in this way, in fact, the jiva is mature enough to leave the subjugative effects of the Maya and reach the Ultimate Reality.

Such a concept is also described in the chapter of Bhagavad Geeta which explains to the aspirant practitioner of yog, how to detach themselves from worldly matters and reach the Devine Detachment.

I will not quote all the shlokas of the BG because I think that here everybody can go to read them in any version printed or online.

This is just a hint, derived by analysis and observation through studies of yog books [Precisely: Patanjali Yog Sutras, Sri Swami Sivananda Saraswati "Kundalini Yoga " published from Devine Art Life Society, Uttrakhand, India, which book contains almost verbatim passages of Yoga Shiva Samhita in the 1914 Chandra version].

Thesis:

The two questions What are Five Layers (Pancha Kosha) of Human? and Where does a Soul attached to the Body? explain various koshas (Sheaths) of the human body. Trimurthi and their respective Shaktis are believed to be different aspects of Supreme Brahman. The same is the case of Devas but they are less powerful than Trimurtis and their Shaktis.

```
What Koshas do Trimurthis and their Shaktis have? For example, Goddess Saraswati represents Knowledge. Does she have Vijananmaya kosha and Anandamaya Kosha?
What about Devas living in Swarga Loka?. Agni Deva represents fire but has form. What Koshas do devas have?
```

share edit following flag
asked Jan 12 '16 at 6:10
The Destroyer♦

```
Comments:
```

> There is a description of Vishnu as seen by Garuda in the Garuda Purana where he describes Vishnu being enveloped in his own creation i.e. aham, mahat, all 10 indriyas 5 tanmatras and 5 mahabhutas, etc. – Archit Jul 2 '20 at 18:08

#### My answer:

The Gods enact not like humans. Shiva is beyond Gunas, he destroyed Kamadeva, being Himself container of Primordial Gunas inherent Everything but and being Himself beyond the Gunas. Asking a similar question requires imagining if Universe performs human actions with a Supernova. The answer is yes and no. Because the substance of the Gods is beyond the Indryias so conceived by the humans inside the Maya. Sources: Sanatana Dharma.

After this due premise I will add that:

The 7 Vyahrtis (Heavens or Upperworlds):

- **Satya-Loka:** Brahma’s Loka or Satya-Loka planetary system is not eternal. Abode of Truth or of Brahma, where atman are released from the necessity of rebirth.
- **Tapa-Loka:** Abode of tapas or of other deities. Ayohnija Devadas live here.
- **Jana-Loka:** Abode of the sons of God Brahma.
- **Mahar-Loka:** The abode of great sages and enlightened beings like Markendeya and other rishis.
- **Svar-Loka:** Region between the sun and polar star, the heaven of the god Indra. Indra, Devatas, Rishies, Gandharvas and Apsaras live here: a heavenly paradise of pleasure, where all the 330 million Hindu gods (Deva) reside along with the king of gods, Indra.
- **Bhuvar-Loka (aka Pitri Loka):** Sun, planets, stars. Space between earth and the sun, inhabited by semi-divine beings. It is a real region, the atmosphere, the life-force.
- **Bhur-Loka:** The Vishnu Purana says that the earth is merely one of the thousands of billions of inhabited worlds like itself to be found in the universe.

The 7 Patalas (Underworlds Or Hell):

- Atala-Loka: Atala is ruled by Bala – a son of Maya – who possesses mystical powers. By one yawn, Bala created three types of women – svairiṇīs, who like to marry men from their own group; kāmiṇīs, who marry men from any group, and the puḿścalīs.
- Vitala-Loka: Vitala is ruled by the god Hara-Bhava – a form of Shiva, who dwells with attendant ganas including ghosts and goblins as the master of gold mines. The residents of this realm are adorned with gold from this region.
- Sutala-Loka: Sutala is the kingdom of the pious demon king Bali.
- Talatala-Loka: Talātala is the realm of the demon-architect Maya, who is well-versed in sorcery. Shiva, as Tripurantaka, destroyed the three cities of Maya but was later pleased with Maya and gave him this realm and promised to protect him.
- Mahatala-Loka: Mahātala is the abode of many-hooded Nagas (serpents) – the sons of Kadru, headed by the Krodhavasha (Irascible) band of Kuhaka, Taksshaka, Kaliya and Sushena. They live here with their families in peace but always fear Garuda, the eagle-man.
- Rasatala-Loka: Rasātala is the home of the demons – Danavas and Daityas, who are mighty but cruel. They are the eternal foes of Devas (the gods). They live in holes like serpents.
- Patala-Loka: The lowest realm is called Patala or Nagaloka, the region of the Nagas, ruled by Vasuki. Here live several Nagas with many hoods. Each of their hood is decorated by a jewel, whose light illuminates this realm.

From: With Ganesha’s Grace, The GaneshaSpeaks.com Team

Hence accordingly to the Loka in which the Devas find themselves in, they will be inherent and coherents with the substance of the matters of that locality.

Yet remember that Gods are both in locality and non-locality and that the Brahma time is different than the human time.

Hence it is not given to any human to know with circumstantial precision everything about what the Gods are actually performing if we consider them as embodied energies.

In the reality Shiva Himself is the Nothingness and at the same time a human, a plant, a stone, everything.

So Shakti is that immense Force which is subjected and at the same time the spring of Him making Him move.

The so called Yoni-Linga and Shiva-Shakti fusion has to do with Super Science,like Quantistic Physics or Mechanics.

Under the energy of Kundalini, we are mere humans and we attempt to direct through Her through senses. Out of ignorance. These were the old tantric schools. This leads to the left tantric path, which leads to a fake awake of the Kundalini, and then you will get stuck into a partial samadhi but not winning the gravity. Hence not going to Moksha.

Vaagmarga in the past did in that way too but is useless.

So that you need to understand AtIndryia Gyaan, non-sensual Knowledge, in order to approach the Non-Locality of the Gods and hence answer yourself to the specific question there above

Comment: Please do not click on "Community wiki" option, that will let anyone from community edit your post. Also this will make post not earnable. That is you'll not earn reputation on upvotes.

Comment: I clicked on "Community Wiki" since the website gave me this option. My post had been edited by Mr_Green. @TheLittleNaruto thank you anyway.

Comment: Thank you @Mr_Green for the emendations.