# Do souls (jeevas) meet or associate even before their first physical encounter?

Tags: belief, atma, rebirth

As said by one of the famous writers the important encounters in our present life have been planed by souls even before the bodies (in control of these souls) have met each other.

Is it true that our soul is already acquainted with some person even before we physically meet that person?

Comment: Be specific and be specific of what do you want to ask .This is what I have understood : You want to ask about Hindu (Scriptural)Mythological/Philosophical opinion on such soul meeting thing?.

Comment: Yes. Whether it is true as per hindu mythological/philosophical

Comment: Which famous writer? Care to quote the author in your question?

Comment: Its just allegory.. How can soul meet ? Its inside aanandamaya kosha and size is smaller than subatomic particle.. Only advanced yogi can make soul come out of their body..Soul is just the witness of body, prana, mann, buddhi and aananda...

Comment: This is not true. It's Vasanas or Karma indirectly responsible for marriage or love towards a particular person. Even term "Soul" here is ambiguous. There are five Koshas for Human body. Only Aanadamaya Kosha changes when we take new birth. All our karmic impressions are retained. See this question [What are Five Layers (Pancha Kosha) of Human?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3073/3500). Some Authors use these kind of Prosodies, Poetic verses just to emphasize some "abstract entity" and they could not be factually correct in all cases.

Comment: There is some evidence for this. Some souls - jivas - are intertwined and meet again and again - albeit it in different bodies - during their karmic journey. Some are so intertwined that Liberation is not granted to one until the other is ready for it also.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda That's interesting. Could you explain more about it Swamiji? Thanks

Comment: @sai My answer was put as a comment instead of an answer because all that I know of this is either anecdotal comments from various holy men or offhand comments in books on the lives of some saints. Not aware of any sruti text that would support it- one way or the other.