# how to understand this body is also conciousness?

Tags: atma, brahma, mind, conciousness

I can understand mind is conciousness because mind resolves into conciousness  during deep sleep but how to understand body is also conciousness.

Comment: Can a body exist without a soul? What is the difference between an alive person and a dead body? Its the presence of soul/consciousness in alive. A clock/electronic device made out of matter is useless without a cell/electricity, similarly a material body withers away without a soul after death. Mind is a sockpuppet of self.

Comment: Yes a body can exist without a soul according to scriptures the body in the 7th month of preganancy.

Comment: Even for a pregnant mother, the child's body is like a machine feeding on the nutrition, air of mother's body containing soul via umblicial chord. Can a fetus develop in a body of dead mother? Death of mother is also death of unborn child, because in reality consciousness/soul is giving birth to another soul, but in Maya an animal or bound soul will think that its body is giving birth to another body, which is false in reality. The same atman gyan is the gist of entire metaphysical spirituality of Shashtras like Geeta, Vedanta etc.,https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36438/20089

Comment: Every body is made of 7 dhatus, static half like bone, marrow etc., come from father, while dynamic half like blood, fat comes from mother and driven by one's soul(given body is based on one's previous births collective karmas) as explained in Shiva Geeta, its known to modern science as XX or XY chromosomes genes(or Sperm-Ovum fusion) while soul is unknown to science as its the seer not some matter which can be verified in some material lab.

Comment: the body does not have consciousness.

Answer (score 2):

Mind does not resolves in deep sleep rather exists in seed form. Had mind merged into consciousness, then samadhi would have ensued. But after waking up, you are still able to recall the experience of deep sleep that you didn't witness a dream. This clearly shows that there was a Seer (Subject) that saw or experienced blankness (object) which is a sign of duality.
Hence understand that mind hadn't been absorbed into Consciousness.

Now, how to understand that the body too is consciousness?
Just take a simple instance of the ocean and a wave arising on the ocean water. Because of ignorance, we (Wave) limit and identify ourself as a body mind complex entity (a name and form) independent of ocean, failing to realise that underlying essence  both Wave and the large expanse of ocean is "Water" itself. In principle, both wave and Ocean is nothing but water. Therefore wave(body) surfacing over the ocean (perceived/unperceived world and beyond) is one Consciousness and has no any separation. The idea of separation arises because of the tendency to identity oneself as a limited name and form entity which is ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

The material body is the annamayakosa. There are 5 kosas or khosas - sheaths which surround the Atman in an individual, the outer material sheath is the annamayakosa. See [Where does a Soul attach to the Body?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/where-does-a-soul-attach-to-the-body) and [What are three Sharira and their relation to five Kosha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14712/what-are-three-sharira-and-their-relation-to-five-kosha) There are multiple questions on this topic to explain the sheaths more fully.

In his commentary on verse I.17 in Sri Vidyaranya Swami's *Pancadasi*, Swami Swahananda writes:

> ...the translation of sarira as 'body' is a bit confusing. It does not mean something with hands, feet, etc. or branches as of trees; but the perishable and perishing outer-coating of the inner consciousness building and guiding it.

The seat of consciousness, the atman, in man is in the buddhi, and although it permeates the body, the outer sheath known as the annamayakosa, it is not the body. When the buddhi withdraws from the annamayakosa, the outer sheath dies. It is because we identify ourselves with the body and think we are the body, that leads us all to delusion rather than identifying ourselves with our true selves, out inner atman. The material body has no consciousness in or of itself.