# To which body the "prana" belongs to?

Tags: body, prana

Every existing living being has at least three bodies: physical, subtle, and causal.

physical organs are related to physical. Manas, buddhi, etc., are related to subtle, and impressions are related to causal.

I want to know the association of prana with these bodies. Does prana belong to one of them?

If yes, to which body does it belong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are three Sharira and their relation to five Kosha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14712/what-are-three-sharira-and-their-relation-to-five-kosha)

Comment: The prana belongs to the pranamaya kosha, which is a part of the subtle body.

Comment: It belongs to the subtle body. Note that the subtle body is also partly physical.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/where-does-a-soul-attach-to-the-body