# What is significance of purple lotus in hands of Goddess Parvati?

Tags: symbolism, parvati

Although I'm not a Hindu, I once had a beautiful dream about a Hindu lady who presented me with a purple lotus. The dream was AMAZING, but I didn't really understand it, but I remember seeing her eyes and experiencing an intense feeling of love.

I recently bought a statue and researched it, the statue turned out to be Goddess Parvati, and when I saw her image, I realized it was the women in my dream!

What is the significance of a purple Lotus flower and Goddess Parvati?

I'd love to learn more!

Comment: Hi, the post related to Hinduism, not personal advice?

Comment: Can you remove personal details and ask about Devi Parvati? Btw, your past life connections may be reason for your dream about Adi Parashakti or Mother Durga or Mother Parvati.

Comment: Hi, I think I have removed them all now, I only included them for context as I felt it may be important to obtain an insightful answer.

Comment: I'd like to know more about the past life connections and how they can appear in dream form, thank you very much for your reply!

Comment: @Danny strong past life Karmas remain as subtle impressions in mind and they can also manifest in dream...

Comment: @Danny Past life Vasanas (impressions) are stored in Subconscious subtle mind and these impressions are responsible for rebirths (cause and effects). You can see [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3075/3500) and [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2407/3500), for more details. As said by Tezz, some impressions also manifest in dreams.

Comment: @Danny you can remove your personal experiences and can ask about significance of lotus or anything about Mother Parvati.

Comment: @Danny I edited your title. is that ok?

Comment: Oh, You seem very fortunate one to have glimpse of Ma Parvati. As you have mentioned you were never aware of this personality, you must take this dream seriously. Parvati is manifestation of Adi Shakti. And *Purple* or deep indigo (maybe you have actually seen Indigo)color is the color of 6th chakra. And Chakra is represented by Lotus. So, your dream seems meaningful as well. You can read about Adi Shakti here. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adi_Parashakti

Comment: @Seeker I think Ajna Chakra (6th Chakra) represents Shiva and Shakti both, but generally Shiva (may be Shakti is included implicitly) as it represents 3rd eye.

Comment: Yes @TheDestroyer Ajnā Chakra deity is Ardhanāreshvara. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajna