# Where does Maya reside?

Tags: maya, ignorance

Jiva is said to be covered in 5 sheath or koshas as you can read [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3073). **My question is - does Maya resides in or part of or is active (not sure what is better word) in any specific sheath?**

When the self is realized and you identify who you truly are (not gross body, not prana, not manas, not budhi) then you are said to be free from maya or ignorance. So it would mean that maya or ignorance was caused due to manas or budhi or due to all of them. Hence my question. Where exactly is the root of maya?

Comment: Winning over senses doesn't mean losing them. It means you control them instead of them controlling you. As long as their is body (anything non aatman), Maya will be there . Trick is to overpower it instead of being overpowered by it.

Comment: mAyA (avidyA?) is beginningless. It has no cause. It resides in brahman according to vivaraNa school of advaita. It resides in jIva according to bhAmati school of advaita.